# Tcl: Delete directory recursively - improving performance using threads

Tags: pthreads, tcl

I wrote a small proc to recursively delete %TEMP% dir on windows which got quite bulky over each execution cycle. 
But it seemed to work slow - it was way faster to manually select different folders inside the %TEMP% path and run deletion on it.
Is there a possibility to use threads / pthreads to delete folders in parallel.
Or an alternate solution.
Need help in the following code.

```
proc DirRecursion {dir args} {    
    set options(-files) ""
    set options(-fileTypesFilter) "ALL" 
    array set options $args
    upvar $options(-files) lf
    #Performing action deletion on files for dir $dir ... please be patient as this might take some time
    if ![catch { append lf " [glob -directory $dir -type f *]"}] {
        } "Found following files to delete in dir $dir"
        foreach f [set lf [regsub -all {\\} $lf {/}]] {
            catch {file delete -force $f}
        }               
    } 
    if ![catch { set ld [glob -directory $dir -type d *]}] {
        foreach d $ld {
            DirRecursion $d -files lf               
        }
    } else {
        puts "No directories to delete in dir $dir" debug
    }
    catch {file delete -force $dir}
}
```

Comment: I don't know that removing entire directories in parallel is ever going to be fast.   The speed is limited by the disk drive.

Comment: Instead of treating `lf` as a string, it would be better to create a list.  Use `lappend`.  Right now, it is likely to break on filenames with embedded spaces.  There's also no need for the `regsub`.  `file delete can handle the native names.  It also appears that you are passing in a file list from the directory above in the next call to DirRecursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you *could* do that (probably by sending requests to [`file delete -force`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M12) into a [thread pool](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/tpool.htm)), it's very unlikely to help at all since the bottleneck will be in the actual reading and writing of the disk, even on systems with an SSD. With an HDD, that's definitely what you'll be waiting on.

You are aware that `file delete -force` already handles the recursive delete case? It's probably faster than what you've written too. Since I suspect you don't actually want to delete the `%TEMP%` path itself (as that's a bit special to other programs in your session too), you can instead do something like this:

```
file delete -force {*}[glob -directory $::env(TEMP) *]
```

Or delete the contents of the appropriate subdirectory instead. One line instead of a complicated procedure…

**Edit**

This will try to delete each entry individually and will continue on even if a directory cannot be deleted due to permission errors.

```
foreach {entry} [glob -directory $::env(TEMP) *] {
  catch { file delete -force $entry }
}
```

Comment: Just want to skip errors on un-delete-able files to cleanup clutter - the above command stops at first error